# Fast Shutter Speed Effect / Shutter Angle (aka "Saving Private Ryan" effect)

Tags: motion-blur, frame-rate

Can anyone think of a way to approach creating a high speed shutter effect in Blender?

In film when you want that jerky action motion you can increase the speed of your shutter, thereby decreasing motion blur, which causes fast action to feel jerky.

This effect was expertly used in Saving Private Ryan:
https://mdkq.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/saving-private-ryan-shutter-speed-effect/

One would think that simply not having any motion blur in Blender would yield this type of result, but it does not come out that way.

Can anyone think of a good way to achieve this effect entirely within Blender?

Comment: In addition to lack of motion blur, it also looks like it has a reduced framerate. It also looks like the camera is moving at a constant but random rate, making its position quite different for each (low fps) "snapshot" (ie camera movement is interpolated every frame, but only every 4'th frame is captured, leading to "jerky cam").

Comment: Interesting @ChristopherBennett I wondered about the frame rate as well with SPR, but apparently it's 24fps, so I don't think that's it, in that particular case.  The jerky camera movement is definitely key, however, a jerky camera movement in Blender at 24fps just looks like a normal jerky camera, and not the 'strobe light' effect of SPR.